# Navbar, headline and text under it

Tags: html, css

Having problems getting the headline and text under my current navbar, seems to hidden behind navbar.
So here's the code.

[image: 1]

Comment: Please create a code snippet and add it to your question. That way we can replicate the problem and assist you in a better way.

Comment: <div class="main-container">
     <h1 class="headline">
 <span>&nbsp;</span>
 <span>OTSIKKO</span>
 <span>&nbsp;</span>
     </h1>
</div>                                                                                                                                        Here's the headliner's code, can't find how to fit it better.. odd to read from that I know..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without having a look at the html markup. But given your problem you should look into the z-index prop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

simply add:

```
z-index: 1;
```

to your .headline and they'll be on top. In your case however you might think about putting a margin on the .main-container and "position: fixed" on the navbar. people tend to scroll pages with a bit of content.

Test, try things out in dev tools in your browser and ask your prof. to give you extra credit for using SO ;P

Comment: Sorry forgot that one!, also apologies for using this app to show the code, cant post it directly here..
So here's the html markup https://i.gyazo.com/85a3b7a5fac0197b7f318ce872ae0cd9.png

Comment: I'm a new contributor to SO but... if you use the editor and paste in the code as text it's easy for people to copy and test the code. It might just be me but without playing with it myself it's hard to give a definite answer. As for a solution i'll edit the answer next.

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <title> My Onepager </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="logo_div">
 <img src="lataus.png" alt="" class="logo">
</div>
<div class="navbar_links">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Step-By-Step</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Rekisteröidy</a></li>
</ul>
</div>       

<div class="main-container">
     <h1 class="headline">
 <span>&nbsp;</span>
 <span>OTSIKKO</span>
 <span>&nbsp;</span>
     </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you try to run it from that? Can't find better way to paste the code here..